# Replace jquery $("body").on for child elements with Vanilla Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

how is it possible to replace this jQuery with Vanilla:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.f_click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("TEST");
    });
});
```

My first try was:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    if (e.target.classList.contains('f_bme_start')) {
        alert('open Search!');
        return false;
    }
}, false);
```

this works, but not on child elements.
Has somebody an idea how to solve this?

I want to replace all my jQuery code because of slow performance.....
THANKS

Comment: This is exactly what you are after: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#delegate

Answer (score 2):

You're only checking the element that was actually clicked, not its ancestor elements.

In modern environments you can use the DOM's [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method (and that link has polyfills for older environments):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const target = e.target.closest(".f_bme_start");
    if (target) {
        alert('open Search!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

That searches through the ancestors of the clicked element for a match for a given CSS selector. If you were hooking the event on a container element other than the `document` or `document.body`, I'd also use [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to make sure the search through ancestors didn't go to an ancestor of the container element:

```
const target = e.target.closest(".f_bme_start");
if (target && e.currentTarget.contains(target)) {
    alert('open Search!');
    return false;
}
```

But there's no need if you're hooking the event on `document` or `document.body`.

Answer (score 0):

THANKS a lot!

what is the best solution?
For performance and for compatibility?
I think this one is best?:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
        console.log(target.classList);
        if (target.classList.contains('f_click')) {
            alert('open without jQuery!');
            return false;
        }
    }
}, false);
```